# How to remove listeners from LinkedHashMap objects when key is removed

Tags: java, android, garbage-collection, linkedhashmap, listeners

I have a `LinkedHashMap` like so:

`private LinkedHashMap<String, Column> columns = new LinkedHashMap<>();`

And I **add** a `Column`:

`columns.put(name, column);`

Where a `Column` has an **object with listeners**.

When I **remove** the column:

`columns.remove(name);`

The listeners are **still active**.

I have tried the `WeakHashMap` and that indeed helped and the listeners **were no more active**.

But `WeakHashMap` **does not preserve** the insertion order.

I have also tried to get the `Column` set it to null and then remove the key from the map but no luck. Listeners were still active.

Is there any suggestion for this ? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have ended up with implementing `onStart` and `onDestroy` lifecycle events when removing them from the `LinkedHashMap`.

Influenced by Android Development, activities and services

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove them from the column not the HashMap

Comment: Sure, but I am removing the columns not the listeners. Any ideas? A column can have a listener or no. I was trying to go vanilla on this eg removeColumn and done in order to avoid to first get the column, then check if it has a listener, remove listener etc.
I mainly don't understand why the object is not gc

Comment: Ended up with this. Adding onstart and ondestroy lifecycle calls